# Website opening with port number 8080

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4, iis-7

I have IIS which hast port 80 and apache has port 8080, my apache website opens in local.apache.com:8080. Is there any possible way I can open the url as local.apache.com without the port number used in url

Comment: This sounds like a standard reverse proxy setup. If you can read up on this and try some configurations yourself, then you should be able to come back and ask a more targetted question

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Change IIS port to something else and set up Apache on port 80.
2. Make another virtual host in IIS that is set up as a reverse proxy to your existing Apache running at port 8080.